# Flip left-right Plotly Horizontal Histogram

Tags: python, plotly

I've made a horizontal histogram as shown on the right in the image below. This can be done using the `orientation` kwyword in matplotlib's `hist()` function, as shown in the code below, which generates the following plot.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#generate some data
data = np.random.normal(size=100)

#define the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

#plot the data as a histogram
ax.hist(data, orientation=u'horizontal')

#move ticks to the right
ax.yaxis.tick_right()

plt.show()
```

Is it possible to flip the x-axis, such that the base of the bars is on the right, and the bars extend out to the left, like the left hand plot in the image below?

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to include the examples as images within the post, not as links; links may stop working in the future, making your question less useful for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is simply to invert the order of the axis limit for the axis you wish to mirror. In this particular case, one can achieve the desired result like so:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#generate some data
data = np.random.normal(size=100)

#define the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

#plot the data as a histogram
ax.hist(data, orientation=u'horizontal')

#invert the order of x-axis values
ax.set_xlim(ax.get_xlim()[::-1])

#move ticks to the right
ax.yaxis.tick_right()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the xanchor (options are 'left', 'right' 'center') of layout.

```
https://plot.ly/python/reference/#bar
```

By setting the xanchor on a horizontal bar chart to right, you should be able to get that effect.

Comment: This seems to be for the colorbar. And it's for a bar chart, not a histogram.